# Adding own symbols for file in gdb

Tags: gdb, symbols, elf

Ok.. so I'm working doing debugging on x86 with gdb.
The particular files in question are stripped so I have no symbols from the binary itself. I have no access to the source code, but a rough idea of what's happening under the hood.

My asm knowledge is just about good enough to decide the purpose of a function and decide its purpose. Thus I can decide on my own appropriate names for functions after looking at them for a while, but I would like to be able to inject these as symbols so that once decided upon they can be used in later debugging..

Does anybody know how to load custom symbols into gdb?
I've considered recompiling gdb with and adding an extra command to the UI to allow loading of a symbol at an address.. I was wondering if it would be possible to create a dummy object file with the symbols I've defined and then load it using add-symbol-file?
Or would it be possible to compile a c program with dummy function and so how force them to be the correct size and at the correct location and then simply load that??

Comment: did you try generating external symbol file yourself from whatever data you gathered.  see here: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html#Separate-Debug-Files and here: http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/debugging-programs-with-a-external-symbol-file/

Comment: See also [How to undo strip - i.e. add symbols back to stripped binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15977961/1362755)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like it should be an easy task, but it turns out to be surprisingly annoying, mostly because ELF as a file format is annoying to generate, so most tools are content with parsing it.

As described [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/How%20gdb%20loads%20symbol%20files), GDB reads the symbol information from two places, first some minimal information from the symbols in the `.symtab` and/or `.dynsym` sections, and afterwards more detailed information from the `.debug_info` section if it is present.

This immediately suggests two possible ways to add the information, either add the symbol to `.symtab` or generate your own DWARF info including the symbol.

However, generating DWARF from scratch seems to be a really uncommon use case, so the only working approach I've found so far is to use `objcopy` to add the symbol to the binary itself:

```
objcopy a.out --add-symbol function_name=.text:0x900,function,global a.out2
```

Note that gdb doesn't like absolute symbols for functions, I had to specify it as an offset into the `.text` section to be useful (i.e., be able to set breakpoints on the function and have it appear in backtraces)

Also, I wasn't able to find any way to modify the "size" field of the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't look for a solution in gdb. I would instead try to figure out how to put the symbols back to the binary. Logically, if it is possible to strip the symbols, then it must be possible to add them back. I'd expect linker (ld) or some other tool to allow that.

I recommend to check all the tools in binutils package (objdump, objcopy, nm, ld, ...) - they are capable of many almost miraculous things!

Tomas

Comment: ld has indeed a --defsym option. So I would do it on a dummy a.out (like ld a.out --defsym whatever=0x1111) and then load that via add-symbol-file

Comment: But that doesn't add function symbols, only absolute symbols