# How to undo strip - i.e. add symbols back to stripped binary

Tags: linux, gdb, valgrind, strip

I have a stripped binary and symbol-file. Is it possible to add the symbols back to binary and  create an unstripped binary.

My use-case is using this binary w/ valgrind.

Comment: i'd say recompile, can't think of anything else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valgrind supports [separate debug files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html), so you should use the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target), and valgrind should work properly with the externalized debug file.

Comment: And no: you can't create an unstripped binary from a stripped one (at least not easily). But you shouldn't need to, as this answer correctly states.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is unclear how can I use this debug file w/ valgrind. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The directions provided in the "answer here" appear to be quite clear. You build the separate debuginfo, and then Valgrind and GDB will automagically load them.

Comment: Thanks - will give it a stry.

Answer (score 18):

For those tools that do not support separate files for debug information, you can **glue the debug sections back to the original binary**.

You can do something along these lines, for example:

- First build a small program that efficiently extracts an arbitrary chunk from a file

  *(note that `dd` will not do this efficiently as we'd have to use `bs=1` to support an arbitrary offset* and *length, and `objcopy -O binary` does not copy sections that are not `ALLOC, LOAD`[※](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925075/how-do-you-extract-only-the-contents-of-an-elf-section))*

  ```
  cat <<EOF | gcc -xc -o ./mydd -
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <macros.h>

  char buf[1024*1024];

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char    *fin, *fout;
    int     fdin, fdout;
    off_t   off;
    size_t  len;
    ssize_t rd;
    int     status;

    if (argc != 5) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s fin skip count fout\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }

    fin   = argv[1];
    off   = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    len   = strtoul(argv[3], NULL, 0);
    fout  = argv[4];
    fdin  = -1;
    fdout = -1;

    if ((fdin  = open(fin,  O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
      status = errno;
      perror(fin);
    } else if ((fdout = open(fout, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0660)) < 0) {
      status = errno;
      perror(fout);
    } else if (lseek(fdin, off, SEEK_SET) == (off_t)-1) {
      status = errno;
      perror("Seeking input");
    } else {
      while (len > 0 && (rd = read(fdin, buf, min(len, sizeof(buf)))) > 0) {
        if (write(fdout, buf, rd) != rd) {
          /*don't bother with partial writes or EINTR/EAGAIN*/
          status = errno;
          perror(fin);
          break;
        }
        len -= rd;
      }
      if (rd < 0) {
        status = errno;
        perror(fin);
      }
    }
    if (fdin >= 0)  close(fdin);
    if (fdout >= 0) close(fdout);
    return status;
  }
  EOF
  ```
- Finally, extract the `.debug` sections and glue them to the stripped binary.

  ```
  objcopy `
      objdump -h program.dbg  |
      awk '$2~/^\.debug/' |
      while read idx name size vma lma off algn ; do
          echo "$name" >&2
          echo " --add-section=$name=$name.raw"
          ./mydd program.dbg 0x$off 0x$size $name".raw"
      done
  ` program program_with_dbg
  ```

Comment: dd can seek to an arbitrary address without shrinking the blocksize to 1. See flag "skip_bytes" in dd's man.

Comment: Note that this doesn't copy the relocations associated with the sections

Answer (score 9):

[elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) comes with the tool `eu-unstrip` which can be used to merge symbol files with executables. The result can then be used in place of the stripped version.

Comment: For anyone else that made the same mistake as myself, the man page is not the best and an interesting decision was made. "The first form puts the result in DEBUG-FILE if -o was not given." If you just provide the stripped from .so file, followed by the stripped to .so.debug file, the ultimate result is placed into the .so.debug file. I think it's safe to say almost anyone would expect the combined symbols to go back into the stripped from .so file. Or maybe their use of 'STRIPPED-FILE' is ambiguous as to 'stripped from' or 'stripped into'?

Comment: For reference:
`eu-unstrip binary binary.dbg` :

binary.dbg now has both the binary and debug symbols

Answer (score 0):

While Ghidra is expected to support .debug files, it`s still easier to merge than to make it read 2 files. 8-)

Following up to the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599967/11435969 it is possible to avoid compiling own copy routine and use regular dd (at the cost of some slowdown - 1 byte copy is not the fastest way):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
BIN=program
DBG=program.dbg
OUT=program.full

objcopy $(
    objdump -h ${DBG}   |
    awk '$2~/^\.debug/' |
    while read idx name size vma lma off algn ; do
        ARGS=$(printf "skip=%llu count=%llu" 0x$off 0x$size)
        echo "$name ${ARGS}" >&2
        echo " --add-section=$name=$name.raw"
        dd if=${DBG} of=$name".raw" bs=1 ${ARGS} status=progress >&2
    done
) ${BIN} ${OUT}
```