# How to add debug symbols to stripped ELF binaries

Tags: debugging, gdb, debian, elf, debug-symbols

I need to disassemble debian binaries with debug symbols and I am using IDA Pro for this. The problem is: IDA doesn't seem to recognize debug symbols if they are stored in a separate file (in the case of debian packages). However, when compiling a binary and keeping the debug symbols in it, IDA has no problem annotating all functions and variables.

**So my question is**: is there a way to add the debug symbols back to the stripped binary? The goal would be to create a single binary with debug symbols. Can one for example use gdb to 1) debug the stripped binary; 2) load debug symbols; and 3) produce a binary that contains these symbols.

One method I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977961/how-to-undo-strip-i-e-add-symbols-back-to-stripped-binary) proposed to copy the debug sections from back into the binary. Unfortunately, this worked only partly and some symbols are still missing. I've verified this using gdb.

Answer (score 1):

For gdb use `set debug-file-directory`

For IDA Pro:

1. open the debug symbol file in IDA Pro
2. export database/typeinfo as IDC script
3. edit IDC script

   1. merge database/typeinfo IDC script manually
   2. comment out DeleteAll()
4. open the stripped ELF file in IDA Pro
5. after the analysis is finished, execute the IDC script