# Is there an easy way to import information from a debuginfo rpm into objdump?

Tags: rpm, disassembly, objdump

For context: when running `gdb` on a stripped binary and while in posession of a debuginfo rpm corresponding to the binary being debugged, all of the mangled function names are replaced by their respective non-mangled equivalents from the debuginfo rpm.

Assume the same essential scenario (i.e. you have some ELF file that has been stripped of all debugging information, and that you have a debuginfo rpm corresponding to the same ELF file that has all the debugging symbols in it). Given those assumptions, is there a quick and easy way to make `objdump` aware of those debugging symbols such that `objdump` outputs the function names from the debuginfo rpm instead of mangled symbols?

I've read through the docs for `objdump`, and it doesn't look like it has the capability to read debuginfo rpms. `objdump -C` is close, but it doesn't give the exact same names as those in the debuginfo rpm, and I really do need the names to be exactly identical.

Alternatively, if there's no out-of-the-box solution, is there a library of some sort for reading the debuginfo rpms that would make it easier to script a "find-and-replace" the mangled `objdump` function names?

Thanks!

Edit: If it simplifies the problem, all the debuginfos are in the same format, DWARF version 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy solution... the `gdb` functionality you are talking about is [a feature of the gdb executable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) and not anything the `debuginfo` RPM is doing beyond just dropping files in the right place.

The only thing I can think of is some kind of un-`strip` - [that's been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15977961/836748) and seems to be non-trivial.